# How do I open a comboBoxColumn with Single click

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, datagrid, combobox

my aim is to implement a datagrid with combobox columns where user could select using one mouse click. 
I have Googled around this question, and found pretty much solutions ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3426765/single-click-edit-in-wpf-datagrid), or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28037675/datagrid-cell-single-click-edit-mode-in-wpf-c)) which works fine, **UNTIL user expands combobox in column one and then selects combobox in column 2. The issue is that on first click first combobox just loses focus and only after second click other combobox is expanded. But, it needs to be done in single click.**

Basically, XAML looks like:

```
 <DataGrid Name="grid" SelectionMode="Extended" HeadersVisibility="Column" SelectionUnit="Cell" >
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Name" Width="*" SelectedItemBinding="{Binding Path=Entity}" DisplayMemberPath="EntityName" >
            <DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
                    <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Path=Entities}"/>
                </Style>
            </DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
            <DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
                    <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Path=Entities, Mode=TwoWay}"/>                                                        
                    <Setter Property="Uid" Value="cbEntMapping"/>
                    <EventSetter Event="SelectionChanged" Handler="CbFirmChanged" />
                </Style>                                                    
            </DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
            <DataGridComboBoxColumn.CellStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                    <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" Handler="DataGridCell_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" />                                                       
                </Style>                                                    
            </DataGridComboBoxColumn.CellStyle>
        </DataGridComboBoxColumn>
        <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Give Up" 
            Width="*"
            SelectedItemBinding="{Binding Path=GiveUp}"
            DisplayMemberPath="EntityName">
            <DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
                    <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Path=GiveUp}"/>

                </Style>
            </DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
            <DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
                    <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Path=GiveUp, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                    <EventSetter Event="SelectionChanged" Handler="CbFirmChanged" />                                                        
                    <Setter Property="Uid" Value="cbEntMapping"/>
                </Style>
            </DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
            <DataGridComboBoxColumn.CellStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                    <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" Handler="DataGridCell_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" />
                </Style>
            </DataGridComboBoxColumn.CellStyle>
        </DataGridComboBoxColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

and here is current implementation of single click edit mode:

```
  private void DataGridCell_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        var cell = sender as DataGridCell;
        GridColumnFastEdit(cell, e);
    }

    private void GridColumnFastEdit(DataGridCell cell, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (cell == null || cell.IsEditing || cell.IsReadOnly)
            return;

        var dataGrid = grid;
        if (dataGrid == null)
            return;

        if (!cell.IsFocused)
        {
            cell.Focus();
        }

        var cb = cell.Content as ComboBox;
        if (cb == null) return;
        grid.BeginEdit(e);
        cell.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Background, new Action(delegate { }));
        cb.IsDropDownOpen = true;
    }
```

Comment: tried using templatecolumn with edit template as combobox and set in edit mode on click ?

Comment: Thanks for reply,
I tried your suggestion, but I still have to click second time if current combobox is expanded.

Comment: for that ---- this should work .... private void UIElement_OnPreviewMouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            combo.IsDropDownOpen = !combo.IsDropDownOpen;
        }

Comment: added formatted answer..

Answer (score 0):

Moved from comments --

Have you tried using templatecolumn with edit template as combobox and set in edit mode on click ?

After that to get combos opening in single click following should work..

```
private void UIElement_OnPreviewMouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
     combo.IsDropDownOpen = !combo.IsDropDownOpen; 
}
```

Comment: That works, partially. It opens combos even previous of was expanded.
The issue is, that on mouse button up, it automatically collapses combobox and that is not a common behavior.

Comment: didn't get u ? for me, it closes the previous combo and open the new one in one click, is it not same for you ?

Comment: on mouse button up it should not close combo. 
User should be able to release the button at any position of the UI and combo should be still expanded. But this is not happening on every mouse button up it just closes combo.

Comment: so when should it close ?

Comment: It should work as common comboBox, so it closes after something is selected or clicked somewhere outside (in this case it should preserve old value).

Comment: then what did you mean when you said -- "on mouse button up it should not close combo. User should be able to release the button at any position of the UI and combo should be still expanded."

Comment: sorry but then I don't understand your question please rephrase it

Comment: Huh!

Agreed, it could make some confusion.
The thing that solution you suggested opens combobox fine in single click, but you have to hold mouse button pressed and select another element. But that's not right, user should be able to perform complete click (mouse button down + mouse button up) and then select an element. In your suggestion, on mouse button up combo will close

Comment: "huh" ? you need to clarify what you want .. !